# Freeze at the start of the Ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: system-installation, freeze, 18.04

I want try the last ubuntu version but it crash. (18.04 / amd64)

I tried differents installations :

1 - Try ubuntu menu , OS load display the desktop and some seconds after, the OS is freezed. mouse can be moved, but when I click on the dot icon/applications, no actions .... alt+F1 F2 .. etc can't be used also

2 - Try ubuntu by : install Ubuntu menu
the first page displayed and as the previous installation, the OS Freezed on the keyboard choice (the cursor wheel is freezed also)

I Installation by an USB key . I downloaded 2 versions of the ISO and check the ISO integrity.

My laptop configuration : RAM:16Gb Intel I7-7700 / Nvidia geforce GTX1050

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks
Ristof

Comment: I got the same issue.. identical processor 1070 graphics, initial screen with language selection loads but is unresponsive

Comment: Did you solved this problem ? I'm having the sam issue. Trying redownloading ISO and everything, still freezez on language selection